# Combine INSERT INTO statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert, vba

I am trying to gather some total numbers in a table based on data in other tables using `SQL` through VBA. I have two `SQL` statements that I have pasted below. These work but they insert the totals into two different records.  I was wondering if there was a way to insert them into the same record? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
TotalVerified = "INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES]) " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID])" & _
    "FROM VerifiedFormularies"
TotalAvailableImport = "INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT]) " & _
"SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) " & _
"FROM ImportMetricsIDs"
```

Edit:

```
   totalVerified = "INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED]) " & _
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt " & _
"FROM (SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM VerifiedFormularies " & _
") AS A " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
") as B " & _
", (SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
"WHERE [IMPORT STATUS]= ""Yes"" " & _
"FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable " & _
") AS C "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not work in ms-access:

```
INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED])
SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt
FROM ( 
    SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt
    FROM VerifiedFormularies
) AS A
, (
    SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt
    FROM ImportMetricsIDs
) as B
, (
    SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt
    FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable 
    WHERE [IMPORT STATUS]= 'Yes'
) AS C
```

Comment: I tried to add a third statement but for some reason it says I'm missing an operator around the `WHERE` statement and I am not sure why

Comment: What does your query look like? Since there is no where clause I don't understand the error message.

Comment: The renaming should be right after the aggregate function, i.e. : `(SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt WHERE [IMPORT STATUS]= 'Yes'`

Comment: Ok I fixed that, now it is giving me a reserved word error in the `SELECT` statement...

Comment: In addition, the from clause precedes the where clause. I updated my answer to reflect the new scenario

Comment: I'm afraid I dont understundom what that means. How many columns are there in the Totals table?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this approach?

```
insert into table
(field1, field2)
(subquery1), (subquery2)
```